# How to serialize data to a given file using ujson library in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using below code to generate json file.

```
f = open("test.txt", 'r')
buffer = f.readlines()
rec_cnt = 1
with open("test.json", "w") as ujson_file:  
for line in buffer:
    data_dict[rec_cnt] = {line}
    if rec_cnt == 100:
        ujson.dump(data_dict.values(), ujson_file)
        data_dict.clear()
rec_cnt +=1
f.close()
ujson_file
```

The issue is whenever I do it by batch, each batch of records are enclosed with [], which is forming an invalid json file.

for example
Input file will be

```
 fruits      Orange       Apple        Kiwi        Banana     Veggies     Tomato       Potatoe      Carrot      Peas       Bigfruits   WaterMelon   cantaloupes  Papaya      melon
```

output file should be:

```
[{Key:fruits, Values: [Orange, Apple, Kiwi, Banana]}][{Key:Veggies, Values: [Tomato, Potatoe, Carrot, Peas]}][{Key:Bigfruits, Values: [WaterMelon, cantaloupes, Papaya, melon]}]
```

Any suggestions of serializing the data with only one '[]' or without '[]'

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and how to write a [MCVE]

Comment: @pvg  Hope the above code change helps. Need help here.

Comment: Can you show us a line from `test.txt`?

Comment: @Johnny I have added the the input file and expected desired output file when we dump in batch. from the example we can batch 1 record

Comment: Where is data_dict defined, and how are you parsing each line from test.txt? Also, you have a failure case in that if you have 111 records in test.txt, you'll only ever write out 100 of them and drop the remaining 11 on the floor-- or if you have less than 100, you won't write anything to test.json at all...FYI.

Comment: @Johnny the text file will be read as From Fruits to Veggies is one record, and Veggies to BigFruits is another record.

Answer (score 0):

`data_dict.values()` is always going to return a list object, which you are writing directly to `ujson_file`.

If this is not what you want, try writing `data_dict.values()[0]` instead. I only see one dictionary per list so I assume this pattern remains consistent.

Comment: I am getting error: "object does not support indexing

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally write entire scripts for people but I've been finding myself sitting around waiting for batch processes to finish all week.

Try this instead. It accounts for the failure case I mentioned earlier, is much easier to read and should accomplish what you're looking for.

```
import ujson

# Define what our keys are
keys = ('fruits', 'veggies', 'bigfruits')

# Define how big we want each batch
batch_size = 100

# Define a method to write a list out to a json file
# (I think the way you did this is the original source of your problem)
def flush(objs):
    with open("test.json", "wb") as ujson_file:  
        ujson.dump(objs, ujson_file, indent=4)

# Use a context manager to handle file I/O
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as input_source:

    # Create somewhere to put stuff to write to file
    output = []

    # Don't read the entire file into memory, you may run
    # out of memory with larger files...
    # buffer = f.readlines()

    # ...instead, load it line by line.
    for line in input_source:
        data = {}

        # Parse the line, make it a list we can iterate through
        line = line.split(' ')

        # Look through the list, store any value that isn't a known key
        current_key = None
        for term in line:
            # Erase spaces
            term = term.strip() 
            # If it's a blank "word", skip it
            if not term:
                continue

            # If it's a key, let's start a new list
            elif term.lower() in keys: # Lowercase the term just in case capitalization is inconsistent
                data[term] = []
                current_key = term

            # We know the current key we're working with; add this to that list
            else:
                data[current_key].append(term)

        # Add the dict to our output buffer
        output.append(data)

        # If we've written enough to flush, flush it
        if len(output) >= batch_size:
            flush(output)

     # We've reached the end of the file. If we have anything left to flush,
     # do it now.
     flush(output)
```

Comment: The files get over written with each batch of data. it does not add data for each batch to the file. Thanks for the code, I have the similar code except calling a separate function for writing the data to file.